# Convert from sequential to Functional API model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following code snippet:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
x = model.layers[0].output
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.abs(x)))
model.add(Activation(activation='tanh'))
```

My question, how to convert these steps into the Functional API Keras model. My confused idea is how to insert the ABS layer into the Functional API models.

Comment: do you mean Functional API ?

Comment: yes, I mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your model with the Sequential implementation and Functional API implementation :

**Here are some imports:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda,Conv2D, Activation, Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential
```

**Here is your implementation using the Sequential Model:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
x = model.layers[0].output
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.abs(x)))
model.add(Activation(activation='tanh'))

model.summary()
```

The summary output:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 252, 252, 16)      416       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_6 (Lambda)            (None, 252, 252, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 252, 252, 16)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Now the implementation with Functional API:**

First, define your function:

```
def arbitrary_functionality(tensor):

  return tf.abs(tensor)
```

And:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(16, (5, 5))(input_layer)
lambda_layer = Lambda(arbitrary_functionality)(conv1)
output_layer = Activation(activation='tanh')(lambda_layer)

model_2 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model_2 .summary()
```

The summary output:

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256, 256, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 252, 252, 16)      416       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_9 (Lambda)            (None, 252, 252, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 252, 252, 16)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Note:** according to the TensorFlow documentation, a better way is to subclass the Layer class. See an example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda).